# How to insert an element in a doubly linked list and keep it sorted - c++

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

This an implementation of doubly linked list in c++
..I try to insert elements in my linked list
so I added the numbers 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 8 , 7
before printing , I call quicksort function
quick sort replaces the last element ( 7 )  , with the previous element (8)
..print function results in the output  : 2,2,2,4 , 7 , 7 
How can this code be modified to get the correct result
Here is my code..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

template <class T>
class node
{
public :

    T data;
    node * next;
    node * previous ;
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{

public:

    string delimeter; // optional: just for printing
    node<T>* addSorted(T v)
    {
       insert(T) ;
       _quicksort(first , last) ;

    }
    void swap ( T* a, T* b )
    {
        T t = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = t;
    }  


    node<T>* get(T v)
    {
        bool found = false ;
        node<T> * Curr = first ;
        while (!found)
        {
            if (Curr-> data == v )
                found = true;
            else
                Curr = Curr-> next;
        }
        return Curr ;
    }


    // operator overloading for printing
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, LinkedList<T> & c);


    LinkedList()
    {
        node<T> * curr = new node<T> ;

        first = last = curr;
        first->next = last ;
        first-> previous  = NULL;
    }


    LinkedList(T value, int initial_size)   // make n elements = value
    {
        node<T> * tempNode ;
        node<T> * curr = new node<T> ;

        first = last = curr;
        first->previous  =NULL;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < initial_size ; i++)
        {
            tempNode = new node<T>;
            tempNode->data = value ;
            tempNode->next = first;
            first->previous  = tempNode;
            first = tempNode ;

        }
    }


    ~LinkedList()
    {
        node<T> * current ;

        while (first  !=  last)
        {

            current = first ;
            first = first-> next;
            delete current;
        }
        delete last;
    }


    void print()
    {
        _quickSort(first, last);
       //bubbleSort(first) ;

        node<T> * Curr = first ;
        while (Curr != NULL)
        {
            cout << Curr-> data <<"\t";
            Curr = Curr-> next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int _size()        // returns No. of elements
    {
        int NumOfelements = 0;
        node<T> * temp = first ;
        while (temp != last)
        {
            NumOfelements++;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        return NumOfelements ;
    }

    void insert(T value )
    {
        node<T> * temp = first ;
        node<T> * dummy ;
        node<T> * n = new node<T> ;
        n->data = value;

        last->data = value;
        last->next = n;
        n->previous = last;
        last = n;
        return;
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            dummy = temp ;
            temp = temp->next;
            if(temp==last)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        dummy ->next = n ;
        n -> previous = dummy;
        n -> next = temp ;
        temp-> previous =n;

      // _quickSort(first, last) ;
       //bubbleSort(first) ;

    }

    /* Considers last element as pivot,  places the pivot element at its
    correct position in sorted array,  and places all smaller (smaller than
    pivot) to left of pivot and all greater elements to right of pivot */
    node<T>* pivot_partition(node<T> *f, node<T> *l)
    {
        // set pivot as l element
        T x = l->data;
        node<T> *i = f-> previous;

        for (node<T> *j = f; j != l; j = j->next)
        {
            if (j->data <= x)
            {
                if (i == NULL)
                    i = f ;
                else
                    i =  i-> next ;

                swap(&(i->data), &(j->data));
            }
        }
        i = (i == NULL)? f : i->next; // Similar to i++
        swap(&(i->data), &(l->data));
        return i;
    }

    /* A recursive implementation of quicksort for linked list */
    void _quickSort(node<T> *first, node<T> *last )
    {
        if (last != NULL && first != last && first != last->next)
        {
            node<T> *p = pivot_partition(first, last);
            _quickSort(first, p->previous);
            _quickSort(p->next, last);
        } 
    }

    T mylast () // even this returns 7 not 8
    {
        return last->data ;
    }

private:
    node<T> * first ;
    node<T> * last ;

};
int main (){
    LinkedList <int> l(2,3) ;


    l.insert(4) ;
    l.insert(8) ;
    l.insert(7) ;

l.print() ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I'm amazed you got as far as crashing. `insert(T) ;` in `node<T>* addSorted(T v)` should probably be `insert(v) ;`

Comment: Compiler may be warning about `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, LinkedList<T> & c);`. It's a bit tricky to `friend` a templated function and then define it elsewhere. Expect to have to ask a question about this when you get to implementing it.

Comment: oh I forgot to write v instead of T
but could you specify the problem ?

Comment: Too many bugs here to provide a good, targeted answer. In `void insert(T value)` there is a `return` statement at the function's outer-most scope. This `return` will always be hit, making everything after it in the function dead code. Before that though, a `node` is manufactured and the `next` pointer is never set. This means what it points to it is likely not a `nullptr` or `a `node` to which the program can traverse.

Comment: Advice: give `node` a constructor so that you cannot forget to set the `previous` and `next` pointers and draw pictures of the list as you operate on it to help visualize what you're doing.

Comment: OK thanks buddy for your time

Comment: now we got over the problem of crash
but it stell prints 7 , 7

Comment: Update the code with your current code so we know where you are at.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed many small issues like styling and `nullptr`. But the big problems were in the constructor and in `insert`. The constructor created one element to much and initialized it with a default value. The `insert` method overwrote the last element. Next time please use a tool for code style before posting it here.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class node {
public:
    T data;
    node* next;
    node* previous;
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList {
public:
    string delimeter;
    node<T>* addSorted(T v) {
       insert(v);
       _quicksort(first , last);

    }

    void swap(T* a, T* b) {
        T t = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = t;
    }  

    node<T>* get(T v) {
        bool found = false;
        node<T>* Curr = first;
        while (!found) {
            if (Curr->data == v )
                found = true;
            else
                Curr = Curr->next;
        }
        return Curr;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, LinkedList<T>& c);

    LinkedList() {
        node<T>* curr = new node<T>;

        first = last = curr;
        first->next = last ;
        first->previous = nullptr;
    }

    LinkedList(T value, int initial_size) {
        if (initial_size <= 0) return;
        node<T>* tempNode;
        node<T>* curr = new node<T>;
        curr->data = value;

        first = last = curr;
        first->previous = nullptr;

        for(int i = 0; i < initial_size - 1; i++) {
            tempNode = new node<T>;
            tempNode->data = value;
            tempNode->next = first;
            first->previous = tempNode;
            first = tempNode;
        }
    }

    ~LinkedList() {
        node<T>* current;

        while (first !=  last) {
            current = first;
            first = first->next;
            delete current;
        }
        delete last;
    }

    void print() {
        _quickSort(first, last);

        node<T>* Curr = first;
        while (Curr != nullptr) {
            cout << Curr->data << "\t";
            Curr = Curr->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int _size() {
        int NumOfelements = 0;
        node<T>* temp = first;
        while (temp != last) {
            NumOfelements++;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        return NumOfelements;
    }

    void insert(T value) {
        node<T>* temp = first;
        node<T>* dummy;
        node<T>* n = new node<T>;
        n->data = value;

        last->next = n;
        n->previous = last;
        last = n;
        return;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            dummy = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            if (temp == last) {
                return;
            }
        }

        dummy->next = n ;
        n->previous = dummy;
        n->next = temp;
        temp->previous = n;
    }

    node<T>* pivot_partition(node<T>* f, node<T>* l) {
        T x = l->data;
        node<T>* i = f->previous;

        for (node<T>* j = f; j != l; j = j->next) {
            if (j->data <= x) {
                if (i == nullptr)
                    i = f;
                else
                    i = i->next;

                swap(&(i->data), &(j->data));
            }
        }
        i = (i == nullptr) ? f : i->next;
        swap(&(i->data), &(l->data));
        return i;
    }

    void _quickSort(node<T>* first, node<T>* last) {
        if (last != nullptr && first != last && first != last->next) {
            node<T>* p = pivot_partition(first, last);
            _quickSort(first, p->previous);
            _quickSort(p->next, last);
        } 
    }

    T mylast() {
        return last->data;
    }

private:
    node<T>* first;
    node<T>* last;
};

int main() {
    LinkedList<int> l(2,3);

    l.insert(4);
    l.insert(8);
    l.insert(7);

    l.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valued time and effort , you've saved the day I guess..
Your modifications just fixed the code but the code had to be handled with a NULL node case and Alhamdulellah it worked
God bless you

Comment: You shouldn't use `NULL` for pointers anymore. You can get some problems that are avoided with `nullptr`.

Comment: Also if this answer solved your problem you should accept it.